# Need help about basic loop pagination function

Tags: php

I need help running the loop function to display pagination (I use jQuery ajax php to display some data).

As an example :

```
<?php
$start_row = 0;
$total_row = 10;

echo "<button>Prev</button>";

for ($i = ($start_row + 1); $i <= $total_row; $i++) {
    if ($i == $current_page) {
        echo "<a style='font-weight: bold;'>[$i]</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a style='font-weight: normal;'>[$i]</a>";
    }
}

echo "<button>Next</button>";
?>
```

The results of the function above will result :

```
[Prev][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][Next]
```

But I want split that numbers per 5 pages to display like this :

```
[Prev][1][2][3][4][5][Next]
```

but `[6][7][8][9][10]` remain hidden

When I click next button, page 2 will display like this :

```
[Prev][2][3][4][5][6][Next]
```

page 5 will display like :

```
[Prev][5][6][7][8][9][Next]
```

till the end of page 10 will display like :

```
[Prev][6][7][8][9][10][Next]
```

Comment: in which way you are sending the pagination value to server? Using php (in url) or using javascript (in ajax)

Comment: There is a lot of tutorials about that in `www`, also here in `SO`.

Comment: javascript (in ajax) sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
As mentioned in a comment, you want to somehow know what page you are on. I assume that this is known in the URI. e.g that your url looks something like:
http://www.example.com/intereesting/articles.php?page=x
```

Comment says current page is in start_row post variable.

```
What you want to do is irritate from the current page or 1 if not set. 

    $current_page = (isset($_POST['start_row'])) ? $_POST['start_row'] : 1;
    $start_row = $current_page;
    $total_row = $current_page + 5;

    echo "<button>Prev</button>";

    for ($i = $start_row; $i <= $total_row; $i++) {
         if ($i === $current_page) {
             echo "<a style='font-weight: bold;'>[$i]</a>";
          } else {
             echo "<a style='font-weight: normal;'>[$i]</a>";
          }
    }
```

The other option is todo it like this

```
$current_page = (isset($_POST['start_row'])) ? $_POST['start_row'] : 1;
echo "<button>Prev</button>";
$i = $current_page;
while ($i  <= $current_page + 5) {
    if ($i === $current_page) {
         echo "<a style='font-weight: bold;'>[$i]</a>"; // This will always be the first value though.
      } else {
         echo "<a style='font-weight: normal;'>[$i]</a>";
      }
    $i++
}
```

Comment: thanks you sir for your answer and explanation, but in this case, im not using url to get parameter, im using javascript (in ajax) because some reason.

Comment: While I understand that, but php cannot magically understand what page you currently are at. 

However what you can do is use the same idea with javascript, but then you need to create placeholder ids that you change with javascript on the dom element. 

If I read this correctly, you dynamically change the content on the page on a click on the link. In that case you shold be able to change the values of the a tag texts when you click it.

Comment: "If I read this correctly,you dynamically change the content on the page on a click on the link", it's correct sir. i succeed get current page based on value of anchor tag then i send via ajax to php ($_POST['start_row']). i just need to split per 5 pages correctly, like [Prev][1][2][3][4][5][Next], but [6][7][8][9][10] remain hidden and when i click page 2 will like [Prev][2][3][4][5][6][Next], the number continue counting till the last page (10). any idea sir?

Comment: I did an edit that uses the post variable. Hopefully that is a place to go from at least.

Comment: I have gotten results like the current page, succesful $_POST, only the correct number layout problem that confusing me :( i just need to split per 5 pages correctly.

Comment: You want $i to start on the current page, and you sent this in, so you want $i to start at $start_row , and you want it to show up five times. That means as $i starts at current_page, that you want the total rows to be current_page + 5. 

This is what the above code does, there is also another way todo this, that might indeed be more optimal that I will now add.

Comment: Oh wait, do you want that if you are on page 7, that is shows 7-12 or 5-9? 

My solutions are all for the first case, for the other you need to have ifs that checks inside the ranges you are and generates pagination based on that.

Comment: from the result sir, i just want the page only show 5 to display like [Prev][1][2][3][4][5][Next] but [6][7][8][9][10] remain hidden, until next page button is clicked, like example page 4 (which is current page) will display like this : [Prev][4][5][6][7][8][Next] and so on. while in last page it will show like [Prev][6][7][8][9][10][Next/disabled]

Comment: i like pagination display on this site : https://www.kaskus.co.id/thread/575d69d4dcd770cb588b4577/asus-laptop-user-community---part-5/?ref=homelanding&med=obrolan_hangat but it's get parameter from uri, i need from javascript (ajax) to achieve pagination like that. any idea sir?